# RichPresence doesn't work anymore with JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I noticed that my bot didn't set RichPresence any more than I looked at it today. The last time I checked it was on Wednesday and the code worked there as well. So I executed it again today and the RichPresence was not re-set as usual. Now I think Discord will have changed its interface.

Now I got the latest JDA version into my project and adapted the code so that the DataObject became a JSONObject and it still didn't work. As 2nd I tried to make my "Spielst" object a RichPresence object. Unfortunately, this didn't work either.

Old Class:

```java
public class Spielst implements Activity {

    private String name;
    private String url;
    private ActivityType type;

    public static  Spielst getSpielt(String name, String url, ActivityType typ){
        return new Spielst(name,url,typ);
    }


    protected Spielst(String name, String url, ActivityType typ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
        this.type = typ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRich() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public RichPresence asRichPresence() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public ActivityType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Timestamps getTimestamps() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setPresence(OnlineStatus status, String state, String details, String application_id,
                            String large_image, String small_image, String large_text, String small_text,
                            long timestamp, long since){
        if(Bot.getInstance().getBot() == null)
            return;
        PresenceImpl presence = new PresenceImpl((JDAImpl) Bot.getInstance().getBot()).setCacheActivity(this)
                .setCacheStatus(status);
        JSONObject data = presence.getFullPresence();
        JSONObject game = data.getJSONObject("game");
        game.put("state",state);
        game.put("details", details);
        game.put("application_id", application_id);
        JSONObject assets = new JSONObject();
        game.put("timestamps",new JSONObject().put("start",timestamp));
        assets.put("large_image", large_image);
        assets.put("small_image", small_image);
        assets.put("large_text", large_text);
        assets.put("small_text", small_text);
        game.put("assets",assets);
        game.put("since",since);
        data.put("game",game);
        ((JDAImpl) Bot.getInstance().getBot())
                .getClient().send((new JSONObject()).put("d", data).put("op", 3).toString());
        System.out.println((new JSONObject()).put("d", data).put("op", 3).toString());
    }
}
```

new Class:

```java
package de.letsplaybar.discordbot.main.utils;

import de.letsplaybar.discordbot.main.Bot;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.ActivityFlag;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.RichPresence;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.EnumSet;


/**
 * @author Letsplaybar
 * Created on 05.09.2017.
 */
public class Spielst implements RichPresence {

    private String name;
    private String url;
    private ActivityType type;
    private OnlineStatus status;
    private String state;
    private String details;
    private String application_id;
    private String large_image;
    private String small_image;
    private String large_text;
    private String small_text;
    private long timestamp;
    private long since;

    public static  Spielst getSpielt(String name, String url, ActivityType typ,OnlineStatus status, String state, String details, String application_id,
                                     String large_image, String small_image, String large_text, String small_text,
                                     long timestamp, long since){
        return new Spielst(name,url,typ,status,state,details,application_id,large_image,small_image,large_text,small_text,timestamp, since);
    }


    protected Spielst(String name, String url, ActivityType typ,OnlineStatus status, String state, String details, String application_id,
                      String large_image, String small_image, String large_text, String small_text,
                      long timestamp, long since) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
        this.type = typ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRich() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public RichPresence asRichPresence() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public ActivityType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Timestamps getTimestamps() {
        return null;
    }



    public void setPresence(){
        Bot.getInstance().getBot().getPresence().setActivity(this);
    }

    @Override
    public long getApplicationIdLong() {
        return Long.parseLong(application_id);
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public String getApplicationId() {
        return application_id;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getSessionId() {
        return "4b2fdce12f639de8bfa7e3591b71a0d679d7c93f";
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getSyncId() {
        return "e7eb30d2ee025ed05c71ea495f770b76454ee4e0";
    }

    @Override
    public int getFlags() {
        return ActivityFlag.JOIN_REQUEST.getOffset();
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public long getSince() {
        return since;
    }

    @Override
    public EnumSet<ActivityFlag> getFlagSet() {
        return EnumSet.of(ActivityFlag.JOIN_REQUEST);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Party getParty() {
        return new Party("party1234", 1, 6);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Image getLargeImage() {
        return new Image(getApplicationIdLong(), large_image, large_text);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Image getSmallImage() {
        return new Image(getApplicationIdLong(), small_image, small_text);
    }
}
```

but by the new class, I miss the syncid and the seasonid and I also don't know where I get them from, because they are not in the documentation on the discordwebsite. has anyone found an implementation that still works for the old version or does anyone know how to get to the two values?

Comment: Just for the record - sending rich presence is not a feature bots have. I assume you're creating a selfbot here, which is against the discord ToS, and thus not supported by JDA.

Answer (score 1):

JDA is library made for bot accounts. Since bots can't use rich presence at all it doesn't actually support setting it. Furthermore there is no real support by discord's API for setting it this way.

The correct way to use rich presence is through an IPC connection with the [discord-rpc SDK](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-rpc) or [Game SDK](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/activities).
You can use a java library for the discord-rpc SDK like [java-discord-rpc](https://github.com/MinnDevelopment/java-discord-rpc) which connects to your Discord client and sets the presence there.

Updating rich presence through the gateway session (like JDA uses) is not documented behavior and subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

Bots can't have a rich presence. Sending a request manually to Discord won't help you. If you're selfbotting, that's against the [Discord TOS](https://discordapp.com/terms).